# Java 2ME Swapping Vector elements

Tags: blackberry, java-me

I want to sort my vector but I need to use a swap function in order to do that... Is there any pre-defined methods like `Collections.swap(vector, index1, index2)` in java2me?

Answer (score 1):

Thats pretty simple actually

```
    private static void swap(Vector src, int i, int j)
  {
    Object tmp = src.elementAt(i);
    src.setElementAt(src.elementAt(j), i);
    src.setElementAt(tmp, j);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, there's certainly a `Collections.sort()`

http://download.oracle.com/javame/config/cdc/ref-impl/cdc1.1.2/jsr218/java/util/Collections.html

**Edit:** And since I'm apparently blind, as Bala R points out below, there's a `swap` as well, exactly as you describe.

Comment: If this is for BlackBerry, then such `Collections` class is missing in the BB API.